# (Python) I want to put the following for loop with return statement on a single line:

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, return, boolean

The first line of code is my failed attempt to put the following three lines on a single line:

```
return (False for char in pin if char not in "0123456789")

for char in pin:
    if char not in "0123456789":
        return False
```

I want to return `True` if all characters in `pin` are digits.

Comment: What do you want to return for a *valid* pin?  `True`?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking, do you want to check every element of `char` to determine if it's in the string `0123456789`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you would have to use `[...]` instead of `(...)` like `x = [False for char in pin if char not in "0123456789"]`.

But I guess you actually ment to check if each character in the specified `pin` is a digit or not. You can use the [`.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function for that like

```
if not pin.isdigit():
    // Handle the error
```

Comment: `isdigit` is not a good choice here.  It will allow all kind of crazy pin like `"꘠꧓"`

Comment: Are you sure `isdigit()` is right here, it looks like the OP is attempting to compare every element of `char` against a string of numbers.

Comment: @wim Which might be a good idea if someone with a foreign language wants to enter his pin in his own language, right? If that is not what is wanted, `isdigit()` is a bad choice here of course. What is your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is not to change the behavior of OP's code, at least not without mentioning that the behavior is being changed

Answer (score -1):

`return [] == [0 for char in pin if char not in "0123456789"]`

The code:

`[0 for char in pin if char not in "0123456789"]`

returns 0 if this for loop is satisfied. Else it returns empty array.
So if you compare it with [] then you will get true/false answers.

Answer (score -2):

This answer assumes you want to return `True` for a valid pin (all the chars are in "0123456789") and `False` for an invalid pin (one or more chars are not in "0123456789").

One way to solve this would be using the built in `all()` function with a list comprehension.  The `all()` function returns `True` if the list is empty or every value in the list is `True`.  It returns `False` if one or more `False` values appear in the list.

First, to generate the list of `False` values use square brackets to turn your expression into a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
[False for char in pin if char not in "0123456789"]
```

Pass this list comprehension to the `all()` function.  This would be done in one line like this:

```
return all([False for char in pin if char not in "0123456789"])
```

If the list is empty (i.e. all the chars are in `"0123456789"`) it will return `True`. It will return `False` if any of the chars are not in `"0123456789"`.

See:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all